# What is the rating presented in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, ratings

Does it show the average rating over a specific period of time? Or a cumulative average of all historical rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86921) from the Apple Developer Forums, it seems to be a source of much confusion for developers, however the default behaviour is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/), which states that the summary rating is specific to each territory and can be reset if the developer so wishes upon releasing a new version of the app

Answer (score 0):

The rating is a cumulative average of all historical rating and segregated for each region (country/territory) app is sold in.

There is a minimum threshold of 5 reviews before the reviews and ratings are displayed to users.

For further details regarding App Store ratings and reviews, go through the support site set up by Apple, [Ratings, Reviews, and Responses - App Store](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/).